# Split action mode does not show on Samsung S-series devices using appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I work on an android app where I am using the appcompat-v7 support library to show a split action bar on narrow devices (ie. phones), all the way down to API level 9. I also use the Contextual Action Mode in the same activity to show a split action mode.

The normal action bar shows split with the action items at the bottom of the screen as expected on every phone I have tested. However, on the Samsung S-series of devices (specifically, I've tested the S3 and S5, running android 4.1 and 4.4.2 respectively), when I activate action mode, the split bar at the bottom disappears and no action items show. If I disable the split action bar, the action mode items show in the top action bar as expected. As both these phones are running versions of android that support the action bar and contextual action mode natively, I imagine that the support library should not be at fault, but I'm honestly at a loss as to what's going on here.

Does anyone have any idea how I can work around whatever samsung has screwed up here?